# Schedule Web Form And Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, c#, .net, windows

I have an `.aspx` file and it runs JavaScript code to push data to Google. It runs on my server. I want to run it once per minute. But the JavaScript must be loaded from the `.aspx` file. I try to call it from a browser for this reason.

1. Is there any elegant way except to load it into a browser? (The JavaScript
   code must be run.)
2. How can I schedule a call to the webpage? (But the browser should be
   closed after it runs.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's a kind of a "webtool" called [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/). You can schedule to run over you webpage, but I'm afraid that Javascript wont be executed.